# How to expand filename without extension in abbreviation in vim?

Tags: vim, command, expansion

I have several abbreviations for [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/):

```
cnoreabbrev Ack Ack!
cnoreabbrev ack Ack!
```

which rewrites `ack` to `Ack!` in vim's command line/mode.

Now I'd like to use file name without extension to ignore it from searches using

```
:echo expand('%:r')
```

I imagined that I'd do it similarly to bash expansion using `

```
 cnoreabbrev acki Ack! --ignore `expand('%:r')`
```

but this doesn't work.

How can I achieve this? I specifically want the abbreviation not a function (but it might be there indirectly) to have an uninterrupted flow where I write `acki` and then immediately search term

Comment: What about just `%<`? Won't it be enough in your case?

Comment: @LucHermitte That's exactly what I needed! Thanks. You can post it as an answer (probably with some explanation how it works)

Comment: Could you please explain more what is the main problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `expand ()` you'll need to play with `c_CTRL-R=`. fortunatelly here you won't need something that complex.

Indeed, `%` is enough to obtain the filename. To keep only its main part you can then use `%<` from plain old vi.

Comment: How is this mechanism (`%<`) called? Where can I find some info on it?

Comment: I don't have a working version of vim with me right now. I guess you have tried `:h %<`. Normally it should be with the other filename modifiers. You should find the link from `expand()` and `fnamemodify()` help. Regarding the behaviour of the command line. I'm  not sure what is in the help. It's old knowledge for me now ^^'